# How can remove "shadow" from xml to simulate onClick?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

Hello I have the following white_button_shadow.xml

**Buton into a layout:**

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/cvLoginBtn"
     style="@style/cro_button.white"/>
```

**And a style for apply this drawable:**

```
<style name="cro_button" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="cro_button.white">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_button_with_shadow</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**white_button_with_sadow.xml**

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button_shadow"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button"
        android:bottom="4px" />

</layer-list>
```

**white_button_shadow**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
            <corners android:radius="28dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="28dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

white_button

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="28dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="@color/gray_light" />
</shape>
```

The question is how can remove the shadow effect when the button is clicked.

I am trying with https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html but I don't know how to use it or if this is not the best option for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Use a `TextView` instead of `Button`

Comment: I try with this code and  TextView instad of Button, but this doesn't work, the `<item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/white_button_shadow"/>` is showed always, any idea?

Comment: It should be a `<selector` and not a `<layer-list`

Comment: Perfect, with button and selector, thanks for your work